# how to disable backticks in codeigniter when using $this->db->select();

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, datatables

I have a function :

```
  function datatables ()
  {
    $this->db->select('
      (CASE 
        WHEN L_Type_Name="Khusus" 
        THEN CONCAT("<i id=",L_Type_ID," class=\"formUpdate\" title=\"Ubah\"></i> <i id=",L_Type_ID," class=\"formDelete\" title=\"Hapus\"></i>")
      END) Option');
    $this->db->from('leave_type');
    return $this->datatables->generate();
  }
```

When executed, error :

```
<h1>A Database Error Occurred</h1>
    <p>Error Number: 1064</p><p>You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'L_Type_ID`, " class=\"formDelete\" title=\"Hapus\"></i>")
      END) Option
FRO' at line 3</p><p>SELECT (CASE 
        WHEN L_Type_Name="Khusus" 
        THEN CONCAT("<i id=", `L_Type_ID`, " class=\"formUpdate\" title=\"Ubah\"></i> <i `id="`, `L_Type_ID`, " class=\"formDelete\" title=\"Hapus\"></i>")
      END) Option
FROM `leave_type`</p><p>Filename: C:/XAMPP/htdocs/sicuti/system/database/DB_driver.php</p><p>Line Number: 691</p>
```

I thought the error occurred because there is a Quote / Backtick that strayed here:

```
<i `id="`, `L_Type_ID`, "
```

then I added the FALSE parameter to remove the Quote / Backtick here :

```
$this->db->select('',FALSE);
```

and here :

```
$this->db->from('',false);
```

however, another error occurs that indicates no table is used :

```
<h1>A Database Error Occurred</h1>
    <p>Error Number: 1096</p><p>No tables used</p><p>SELECT *</p><p>Filename: C:/XAMPP/htdocs/sicuti/system/database/DB_driver.php</p><p>Line Number: 691</p>
```

I removed the FALSE parameter in one
$this->db->select() and $this->db->from(), same error 1096.

What's wrong with my code?
Previously I thank you ...

https://pastebin.com/k6Mbfrcx

Comment: For custom queries you may use `$this->db->query( .... )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for answering, I've found my mistake, I should have used the datatable query builder: ($this->datatables) instead of CI: ($this->db).

```
$this->datatables->select('
     (CASE
       WHEN L_Type_Name="Khusus"
       THEN CONCAT("<i id=",L_Type_ID," class=\"formUpdate\" title=\"Ubah\"></i> <i id=",L_Type_ID," class=\"formDelete\" title=\"Hapus\"></i>")
     END) Option', false);
$this->datatables->from('leave_type');
return $this->datatables->generate();
```

[CODE IN PASTEBIN](https://pastebin.com/SXRa61gc)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using false in both `from` and `select`, you only need to use `false` in `select()`

Try using this :

```
$this->datatables->select('
        (CASE 
            WHEN leave_type.L_Type_Name="Khusus" 
            THEN CONCAT("<i id=",leave_type.L_Type_ID," class=\"formUpdate\" title=\"Ubah\"></i> <i id=",leave_type.L_Type_ID," class=\"formDelete\" title=\"Hapus\"></i>")
        END) Option', false);
$this->datatables->from('leave_type');
return $this->datatables->generate();
```

Comment: thanks, but I've done that way, but still an error like this:
`code`<h1>A Database Error Occurred</h1>
  <p>Error Number: 1096</p><p>No tables used</p><p>SELECT *</p><p>Filename: C:/XAMPP/htdocs/sicuti/system/database/DB_driver.php</p><p>Line Number: 691</p>`code`